# Rxjava and Volley Requests

Tags: android, android-volley, rx-java

My question should sounds something like stupid, but i am just jumping from **Asynktask to RxJava**.
So:

> Is possible to use RxJava Observable with Volley Requests?, it means,
> using future requests.

I ask this, because another httpClient like *retrofit* uses RxJava very well, but personally love Volley, so is it possible?

**Edit**

Base on the first answer, i get that it is possible.

> Could you share
> some sample showing how to do that?

Comment: yes. Use RequestFuture and Observable.from

Comment: ok,  if it is possible, will edit my question to get some sample. In volley to return value, i normally use callbacks, but here, i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I just happen to be trying to figure out how to do this, too. I am reading this right now: http://code.hootsuite.com/observing-observables-in-mobile-rxjava-for-android/

Comment: thanks, i just read this, and its very helpfull. Will try some code

Comment: @MaxPinto RequestFuture in Volley is a listener that wraps into a future, which you can use with Rx.

Comment: yes, i found the answer, will show my code to hel some other

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> THIS CODE WOKS WITH THIS LIBRARY

```
api 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'
```

Finally and thanks for your answer i find a solution that want to share:

In my case i use Activities, but for fragment should be more or less equal.

And i want o get a JsonObject in response, but could be your custom Volley implementation.

```
 public class MyActivity extends BaseActivityWithoutReloadCustomer implements Observer<JSONObject>

{
private CompositeSubscription mCompositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
private Activity act;

 /**
 * @use handle response from future request, in my case JsonObject.
 */
 private JSONObject getRouteData() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    String Url=Tools.Get_Domain(act.getApplicationContext(), Global_vars.domain)+ PilotoWs.wsgetRoutesbyUser+ Uri.encode(routeId);
    final Request.Priority priority= Request.Priority.IMMEDIATE;
    Estratek_JSONObjectRequest req= new Estratek_JSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url,future,future,act,priority);
    POStreet_controller.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    return future.get();
}

 /**
 *@use the observable, same type data Jsob Object
 */
 public Observable<JSONObject> newGetRouteData() {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<JSONObject>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<JSONObject> call() {
            Exception exception;
            try {
                return Observable.just(getRouteData());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                Log.e("routes", e.getMessage());
                return Observable.error(e);
            }
        }
    });
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle instance) {
    super.onCreate(instance);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
    act = this;

    /**
     * @condition: RxJava future request with volley
     */

     mCompositeSubscription.add(newGetRouteData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this));
 }


@Override
public void onCompleted() {
    System.out.println("Completed!");
}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) {
    VolleyError cause = (VolleyError) e.getCause();
    String s = new String(cause.networkResponse.data, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    Log.e("adf", s);
    Log.e("adf", cause.toString());
}

@Override
public void onNext(JSONObject json) {
    Log.d("ruta", json.toString());
}
```

For me, it just works. Hope helps some one.

**Edit**
*Estratek_JSONObjectRequest.java*

```
public class Estratek_JSONObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest{
Activity Act;
Priority priority;

public Estratek_JSONObjectRequest(int method, String url,
                                  JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                  ErrorListener errorListener,Activity act, Priority p) {
    super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    this.Act=act;
    this.priority=p;
}

public Estratek_JSONObjectRequest(int method, String url,
                                  Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                  ErrorListener errorListener,Activity act, Priority p) {
    super(method, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    this.Act=act;
    this.priority=p;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders()  {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+Tools.mySomeBearerToken);
    return headers;
}

//it make posible send parameters into the body.
@Override
public Priority getPriority(){
    return priority;
}

protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String je = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        if (je.equals("null")){
            je="{useInventAverage:0}";
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(je), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
        else
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(je), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var3) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(var3));
    } catch (JSONException var4) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(var4));
    }
}
```

}

This is like Volley constructors, but i make my own custom, to send some headers, like bearer token, content-type, send priority, etc.
Otherwise is the same.

> FOR THE [**RXJAVA2**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) LIBRARY, THIS IS THE WAY:

*> build.gradle should have something like this:*

> api "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2":

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CompositeDisposable         mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle instancia) {
    super.onCreate(instancia);
    setContentView(R.layout.sale_orders_list);

    // disposable that will be used to subscribe
    DisposableSubscriber<JSONObject> d = new DisposableSubscriber<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            onResponseVolley(jsonObject);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            // todo
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("Success!");
        }
    };

    newGetRouteData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(d);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    /**
     * @use: unSubscribe to Get Routes
     */
    if (mCompositeDisposable != null){
        mCompositeDisposable.clear();
    }
}


/**
 * @condition: RxJava future request with volley
 */
private JSONObject getRouteData() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException,RuntimeException {
    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    String Url = "https//miapirest.com/api";
    JSONObjectRequest req= new JSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url,future,future,act,priority);


    VolleyInstance.addToRequestQueue(req);

    return future.get();
}

/**
 * @condition: this function create a new Observable object and return that if success or
 */
public Flowable<JSONObject> newGetRouteData() {
    return Flowable.defer(new Callable<Publisher<? extends JSONObject>>() {
        @Override
        public Publisher<? extends JSONObject> call() throws Exception {
            return Flowable.just(getRouteData());
        }
    });
};
```

}

Comment: Could you post `Estratek_JSONObjectRequest `? or some generic form of it?

Comment: i just have added few moments ago

Comment: What does "je" mean in `parseNetworkResponse`? Is that just something specific to your data?

Comment: yes, it is specific return, in your case you can just as normal

Comment: your code has a litter error~
if meet a exception like `authfail exception `create by volley, my program will throw an error,
I fix catch like this
`             try {
                    return Observable.just(future.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return Observable.error(e);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    return Observable.error(e.getCause());
                }
`

Comment: You are right, i found ruta too, but o havent edited this. Thanks for that

Answer (score 5):

Good news is that [Mr.张涛 kymjs](https://github.com/kymjs) modified Google Volley into **[RxVolley](https://github.com/kymjs/RxVolley)**, Removed the HttpClient and RxJava support.

> **RxVolley = Volley + RxJava + OkHttp**

Complete documentation available at http://rxvolley.mydoc.io/

P.S:
*I'm currently thinking of how to use RxVolley with support for multiple custom JSON converters like retrofit!*

Comment: another a little more extended version including converters also is jus: https://github.com/apptik/jus

Comment: @djodjo Thanks for sharing !

Comment: why httpClient removed?